# What is the largest asteroid humanity could survive?

Tags: physics, weapons, hard-science

An asteroid is hurtling towards Earth with the same trajectory as the one that killed the dinosaurs. Current human civilisation gets one year warning and will do everything it can to secure our survival. What is the smallest size of this asteroid such that, despite all our efforts, we would still be wiped out?

**Assumptions**

- Size could be mass, or something else like diameter. If necessary
  assume asteroid is spherical and uniform, (unless there's some better
  way you know of for modelling asteroids)
- In every particular except size (mass or diameter)--e.g., velocity, density,
  angle of impact--the asteroid is identical to the Chicxulub impactor
- Humans have 1 year of
  warning. Assume everyone will cooperate and treat the asteroid as
  singular matter of utmost priority, and that all reasonable resources
  can and will be diverted to methods for deflection or breaking it up
  etc
- Asteroid is a solid cosmic object on a collision course with
  Earth. If it needs to be much larger than Earth to fulfil these
  criteria, and/or gravitational effects need to be considered, so be
  it
- For humanity to 'survive' it's sufficient that a substantial proportion,
  say 10%, of the human race survives. However a) they must survive
  permanently, not temporarily escape only to be faced with an
  uninhabitable world where they'll die months later, b) no escape into
  space or anything like that.

I am mainly interested in what the most powerful technologies humanity could have ready within one year would be, how much of them and what explosive power, if humanity devoted all resources practically possible to the problem as a matter of species survival--and what size of asteroid would be too big for them to make a difference.

The more technically detailed the answer, the better!

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Mind that in the title you ask about surviving, in the body you ask about being wiped out. And asking about what is the largest size of an asteroid that could wipe us out makes no sense.

Comment: I think that the question title and intro are a bit misleading. You ask about the largest possible asteroid humanity could survive; that makes me think of whether we would survive the impact. I'm pretty sure that any impactor short of Theia would be survivable by a small group of people in a massive bunker, yet diverting an asteroid of that size with a one year warning is beyond our wildest dreams. Why don't you ask for the most effective methods to divert or destroy asteroids that are large enough to wipe out humanity, since you're interested in that technology rather than the survivability?

Comment: Is tuning Earth into something Mars-like count? I mean that with some preparation and good luck even ripping our planet apart can be suvivable - in a bunker in newly formed large asterod. What is a acceptable damage to planet, irregardless of human suvival?

Comment: I think if you're expecting a hard science answer, you need to ask a hard science question. There are matters of impactor mass, trajectory, velocity, angle of impact, location of impact and the like that will radically affect the answer. Also, you really need to proofread the body of your question. I'd edit the offending sentence myself, but I'm not sure what you actually intend to mean there.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica right, of course, I meant "smallest such that" or "largest such that not". I've edited to show this.

Comment: @KeizerHarm edited wording ("small" to "substantial" proportion): if you think humanity's best bet (that would get it to survive the biggest asteroid) is a bunker that could house and save 10% or more of people indefinitely, go ahead and answer with that

Comment: @elemtilas good point, I have edited the question. If it's definitive enough now, can it be reopened?

Comment: Your question is still two questions at once: asteroid survivability and methods of asteroid deflection/destruction, both of them are vague. The first one because speed and angle matters as much as size: there's many factors. And the question asking for all the possible technologies available to prevent the destruction is almost too broad to stand on its own, let alone coupled with the survivability aspect. You should really hone in and ask either for the biggest asteroid we could survive without efforts, or the most effective ways to neutralise a Chicxulub-size impactor with one year warning.

Comment: To put it another way: there are possible asteroids that would wipe us out, but be easy to deflect. There are also asteroids impossible to deflect that are not going to kill nearly as many people. Your question has two unknowns: asteroid specifics, and deflection method specifics. You can't be vague about both those things, I would advise to put one of them in stone and let us solve the other one

Comment: @KeizerHarm I am clear on asteroid specifics as far as I can tell: "In every particular except size (mass or diameter)--e.g., velocity, density, angle of impact--the asteroid is identical to the Chicxulub impactor". As for the question of possible technologies, I do not expect a survey: the goal is judicious judgement of what humanity would choose. (Given that it's unanimously agreed all resources should be pooled to the task).

Comment: As for multiple questions: I think everyone appreciates that you're not conducting a survey!  The take-away point for you is to edit out the technology portion of this query and ask that in a separate question. Each question here (or in any SE forum) should be focused on one single problem. This query is focused on size. Ask a different question that focuses on tech! That's how to get this question reopened, and also get the answers you're looking for!

Comment: @elemtilas Not really sure what to say--what do you mean exactly by "the technology portion"? My focus isn't on tech. It's on survivability (given human efforts). What efforts humans would make isn't something I'm interested in, in and of itself, but rather how large an asteroid would have to be that such efforts would have no chance of working. In what way does the question as currently written not seem to focus on one single problem?

Comment: @elemtilas To elaborate, I'm aware that to answer my actual question requires *consideration* of those efforts/technologies. I didn't expect that consideration to be comprehensive. I'm looking for people to say 'hmm: this is what I think would be humanity's best bet to stop the biggest possible asteroid, technology-wise'--ideally, either different people will have different opinions, or there will be common consensus--and then calculate the upper bound for asteroid size for this to have a chance of working (such that >10% of humanity is saved)

Comment: I think the issue is that it seems like you're trying to get a two-for-one special by asking not only the title question, about asteroid size, but also about technologies that can deal with it. What I'm saying is that if you're really just asking about asteroid size, then it would probably be best to edit out the technology portion. Keep in mind: different technologies applied at different times will mean that larger or smaller asteroids are survivable. That's why I suggest separate questions.

Comment: Re your second recent comment: I understand that you're kind of fishing for opinions. That's probably one reason why the question was closed. A little too much fishing! Stack Exchange likes narrowly focused questions. If you's asked "given the availability of XYZ tech, applied at such-and-such a time, what is the largest asteroid..." then you'd've been okay! Scenario questions like that are perfectly fine and relatively narrow scope. When you put too many variables into play, questions tend to get out of hand.

Comment: @elemtilas I see what you mean. Made a small edit accordingly. I would maintain that, while 'narrow focus' may be debatable, the question is objective (not asking for subjective opinions): 1) what would be the most powerful technology humanity would be likely to bring to bear in this scenario; 2) how big an asteroid could it stop. I was tempted to make those into two questions but refrained because I suspect the first one would have rather simple consensus (e.g., see the answer below). If you still think it's a good idea, I might

Comment: Do not underestimate the site, narrow questions with ostensibly obvious conclusions often elicit the most creative responses :) Multiple smaller questions is the way to go when you're doubting about whether the scope is too broad

Comment: Kind of up to you -- the question has been reopened, so the point is moot. I'd personally split it into two obviously related questions, though. I have the feeling that the real answer will be "unsurprisingly small".

Answer (score 3):

Checkout Purdue University's online impact effect calculator, at:

https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/ImpactEffects/

Diameter is not the only factor at play. You need to consider angle, density, and depth. A massive asteriod of ice gently brushing past the ocean is of lower consequence than an iron asteroid of the same size hitting granite at a 90 degree angle.

Assuming worst case (Iron, 72km/s, into rock)

- 1km diameter:  [A crater 48.8 km wide, 954 meters deep. 2.59 x 10^6 MegaTons TNT. Other side of planet survives](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/cgi-bin/crater.cgi?dist=20000&distanceUnits=1&diam=1&diameterUnits=2&pdens=&pdens_select=8000&vel=72&velocityUnits=1&theta=90&wdepth=&wdepthUnits=1&tdens=2500)
- 10km diameter: [A crater 372 km wide,  1.76 deep. 10.9 ricter scale earthquake or higher felt on entire planet. Humans may just survive in special bunkers.](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/cgi-bin/crater.cgi?dist=20000&distanceUnits=1&diam=10&diameterUnits=2&pdens=&pdens_select=8000&vel=72&velocityUnits=1&theta=90&wdepth=&wdepthUnits=1&tdens=2500)
- 50km diameter: [A crater the size of Australia. 3.24 x 10^11 MegaTons TNT. 12.3 richter scale earthquake and 97db air pressure wave felt on opposite side of planet. Earth stays on its orbit, but is wiped out](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/cgi-bin/crater.cgi?dist=20000&distanceUnits=1&diam=50&diameterUnits=2&pdens=&pdens_select=8000&vel=72&velocityUnits=1&theta=90&wdepth=&wdepthUnits=1&tdens=2500)

Your question is a little unclear, "What can we survive?" vs "What do we have no chance of surviving?". 1km is clearly survivable if you're prepared and on the other side of the planet. 50km is clearly not survivable. In between is a sliding scale of other factors, including luck, impact site, weather patterns, impact angle, and human ingenuity.

## Can we stop it?

I haven't mentioned any "Go into space and stop it" style missions, 1 years notice is officially not enough time get our act into gear. [NASA needs a minimum of 5yrs](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/CHRG-113hhrg80552/pdf/CHRG-113hhrg80552.pdf). Almost all of the deflection strategies we know of (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_impact_avoidance#Collision_avoidance_strategies) require getting a spacecraft to the asteroid years before impact, and that can only happen with more warning, and good launch windows.

Theoretically we could get our act into gear anyway, but watching us bumble with COVID19 I think this is a bit of a stretch, but lets assume we do for sake of example.

For example, using "Apophis" asteroid as an example, which is an asteroid very close to impacting Earth, assuming it is impacting in exactly 1 year from today, we have [a few launch windows](https://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/traj_browser.php?maxMag=25&maxOCC=4&chk_target_list=on&target_list=Apophis&mission_class=oneway&mission_type=flyby&LD1=2020&LD2=2022&maxDT=2.0&DTunit=yrs&maxDV=7.0&min=DV&wdw_width=-1&submit=Search#a_load_results) for a kinetic impact:
[image]
There are 7 other trajectories, earliest launch date is Sep 4th 2020, Last launch date is in Jan 26 2021. Impact for those launches is between Feb 27 2021 and Apr 16 2021, which would give between 6 and 4 months for the trajectory to diverge after the impact.

The larger the asteroid, the harder, or earlier, or more often, you need to use to your kinetic impactor. Apophis is a relative simple one, it's only 325m in diameter. We'd launch a few missions (as a backup), but a single kinetic impactor with 6 months for the change to diverge could save the day.

Landing something on the asteriod, or flying near it (Gravity tractor, Ion beam, Mass driver, attaching a rocket engine, attaching a solar sail, releasing steam in front of it, tether an ballast, etc.), which are our best hope of deflecting a planet killer, are a lot trickier to do with only a years notice. Using the same asteroid orbit, but assume the mass is too large for a kinetic impactor, we only have 1 launch window (Feb 11th 2021), with an arrival date of May 2nd.
[image]
That only gives 3 months for it to deflect the asteroid before impact. Most of our known methods need years to deflect, so the larger asteroids are essentially unstoppable with only 1 years warning.

Comment: You are not answering " What is the largest size of this asteroid such that, despite all our efforts, we would still be wiped out?"

Comment: @Ash Good answer; it would be good as L.Dutch says to get an upper bound. We are interested only in "What do we have no chance of surviving?", with the caveat that a small number of people (<10% of human population) hunkering down in bunkers or escaping into space because they have the means doesn't count as survival